# Who gives good advanced Silverlight 4 courses?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've been trying to find a good advanced Silverlight 4 course, but can't really find anything. I've found this:

http://www.develop.com/training-course/silverlight-4

But the most interesting topics are only talked about in the course material, not in the actual course. The extra topics from this course which is of particular interest, are:

Working with Files: local files, Isolated Storage, data files, zip files.

Extensibility: working with MEF to build extensible applications

PRISM: using PRISM (Composite Application Guidance) to structure Silverlight applications

Also: Test driven development with Silverlight would be good to learn better.

Does anyone know anyone who gives good courses which include these topics? I'm not a total Silverlight newbie, but not an expert either. Preferably the course will be held in Europe or Eastern USA.

Chr.

Comment: Personally, I find I get more out of reading books. :) A course can only cover so much. ;)

Comment: I get most out of watching videos and reading online - but sometimes there just isn't a substitute for having a conversation with someone who really knows what (s)he's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agilitrain offers an advanced course. Check out https://agilitrain.com/. This is the company that offers the "Silverlight Tour" courses. I haven't been to any of their offerings, but the instructors are well known in the Silverlight arena. (Shawn Wildermuth and Erik Mork are two of them.)

Take a look at the web site. They display full course outlines and bios of the instructors.

The prices (as with any course) are hefty for an independent programmer/consultant, but if you have a corporation footing the bill, the prices seem a bit more competitive.

Comment: The price is no problem - the problem is that all of their advanced courses in the coming months are on the west coast of the USA. As I live in the outskirts of Europe - traveling so far for a two day course just isn't an option.

Comment: Right. They mostly offer courses in the US and Canada. However, if you go to www.silverlight-tour.com (associated with Agilitrain) they have some European stops in the coming months.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good resource for MEF and Prism: http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/

Erik provides some really useful videos explaining the topics.  Not exactly a course per se though.

And here is Channel9's collection of Silverlight 4 training courses: http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/

There's at least one covering MEF.

The following is a link to ScottGu's blog.  This is another collection of pretty useful Silverlight 4 training videos: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/22/silverlight-4-training-kit.aspx

That should be a good start. :)

Comment: Thanks for great links - I've watched one of the videos, and it was very good. I'm still looking for a real live course, though, to be able to ask questions etc ;-)