# Where can i learn advanced silverlight concepts?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Can anybody refer any resource where i can learn advanced silverlight concepts like creating complex custom controls or any of other advanced concepts? If any book is available then also please mention.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question but it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441159/who-gives-good-advanced-silverlight-4-courses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Silverlight 4 in action](http://www.manning.com/pbrown/) which comes from [Pete Brown](http://10rem.net/blog) who works at Microsoft.

You can never go wrong by heading directly to the [Silverlight site](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/) which has a learning section specifically geared towards coming up to speed with Silverlight, advanced topics as well.

If you reside in a state where the [SL tour](http://silverlight-tour.com/) comes to town and have the available funding; you could get an intense 3 day course on varying SL4 concepts. It is put on by [Shawn Wildermuth](http://wildermuth.com/) who is fairly prevalent in the SL community.

Erik Mork via [Silver Bay Labs](http://www.silverbaylabs.org/) provides varying videos which touch on a range of topics and have proven beneficial to me in varying scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a sub-set of WPF, so try looking for WPF programming tips!